# R: How to merge the values in two columns?

Tags: r, merge

I am trying to do an outer join to merge two datasets. Here I do the join on the field "id":

```
> df_01
  id lat   B
1  3  45 212
2  4  46 212
3  5  46 211

> df_02
  id lat   A
1  1  45 100
2  2  45 101
3  4  46 100
4  5  46 122
5  6  46 121

> merge(df_01, df_02, by="id", all=TRUE)
  id lat.x   B lat.y   A
1  1    NA  NA    45 100
2  2    NA  NA    45 101
3  3    45 212    NA  NA
4  4    46 212    46 100
5  5    46 211    46 122
6  6    NA  NA    46 121
```

(The "id" determines the value in the "lat" field.)

My question is: how do I now merge the columns "lat.x" and "lat.y"? I just need one column, say "lat.x", with the non-NA value thus:

```
  id lat.x   B lat.y   A
1  1    45  NA    45 100
2  2    45  NA    45 101
3  3    45 212    NA  NA
4  4    46 212    46 100
5  5    46 211    46 122
6  6    46  NA    46 121
```

Many thanks,
Bill

Comment: Thanks oshun, akrun and Chinmay for your quick responses and three different approaches - all work a treat!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like join() from the plyr() library.

```
require(plyr)
df_03 <- join(df_01, df_02, by="id", type="full")
df_03 <-  df_03[order(df_03$id),]  #Optional sorting by id
df_03

#  id lat   B   A
#4  1  45  NA 100
#5  2  45  NA 101
#1  3  45 212  NA
#2  4  46 212 100
#3  5  46 211 122
#6  6  46  NA 121
```

Answer (score 0):

After we `merge` the datasets using the code in the OP's post, use either `pmax` or `rowMeans` to `transform` the 'lat.x' column.

```
res <- merge(df_01, df_02, by="id", all=TRUE)

res1 <- transform(res, lat.x= pmax(lat.x, lat.y, na.rm=TRUE))
res1 
#  id lat.x   B lat.y   A
#1  1    45  NA    45 100
#2  2    45  NA    45 101
#3  3    45 212    NA  NA
#4  4    46 212    46 100
#5  5    46 211    46 122
#6  6    46  NA    46 121
```

Or

```
 transform(res, lat.x= rowMeans(cbind(lat.x,lat.y), na.rm=TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do is pass `c("id", "lat")` as argument to `by` parameter

```
df_01
##   id lat   B
## 1  3  45 212
## 2  4  46 212
## 3  5  46 211

df_02
##   id lat   A
## 1  1  45 100
## 2  2  45 101
## 3  4  46 100
## 4  5  46 122
## 5  6  46 121


merge(df_01, df_02, by = c("id", "lat"), all = TRUE)
##   id lat   B   A
## 1  1  45  NA 100
## 2  2  45  NA 101
## 3  3  45 212  NA
## 4  4  46 212 100
## 5  5  46 211 122
## 6  6  46  NA 121
```